# What do light purple color mean in uTorrent

Tags: windows-7, windows, bittorrent, utorrent

I run uTorrent 3.1.2 in my Windows 7 PC. When I download one file, I see some purple colored lines under Files Tab > Pieces. Below is an image of what I am telling (little resized);

[image]

I think that the light green color indicates downloaded parts. But I have no idea about purple lines. The file is a streamable mp3 file.

The connection speed is very low, about 5KB/s down and 1KB/s up. The done file size is not progressing in a smooth way (usually changes in KB are visible), it stays as it is for sometime and then changes to a size (changes in MB), and again the same thing.

Questions:
Why does this happen?
What does the purple color mean?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you even attempt to Google this or look yourself?

Comment: Its pretty clear what it stands for, the peice of the file is being downloaded, as the green part stands for it already been downloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the **graphical progress bar**: You'll notice that there are different colors displayed for different blocks. They are as follows:

1. Purple is downloading
2. Green is downloaded
3. Dark purple is downloading in Endgame mode.

> However, the official colours are
>
> 1. Dark blue means the data has been downloaded and written to disk.
> 2. Medium blue means the data has been downloaded, but remains in the cache in memory, unwritten to disk.
> 3. Light blue means the data has been requested from a single peer.
> 4. Green means the data has been requested from multiple peers. Blocks only turn green during endgame mode.
> 5. White means the data is is available in the swarm, but has not yet been downloaded.
>
> People have commented that they *suppose blue refers to purple in the manual.*

[Source](http://forums.bakabt.me/index.php?topic=35539.0)

> UTorrent uses different icons to indicate the status of a downloading
>   torrent. **Downloading** torrents are indicated by a coloured square
>   with a white arrow pointing down.
>
> If the square is **purple**, the indicated torrent is queued to
>   download but has not begun downloading yet.
>
> If the square is **red**, the indicated torrent is downloading but
>   there is a tracking error that needs to be resolved.
>
> If the square is **blue**, the indicated torrent is currently
>   downloading.
>
> ---
>
> A torrent that is **uploading** or seeding is indicated by a coloured
>   square with a white arrow pointing up.
>
> If the square is **red**, then the torrent is seeding but there is a
>   tracking error that needs to be resolved.
>
> If the square is **purple**, the torrent is queued to seed but is not
>   currently uploading data to other peers.
>
> If the square is **green**, the torrent is seeding and its data is
>   being uploaded without error.

[Source](http://www.ehow.co.uk/about_6557150_do-red-files-mean-utorrent_.html)

Comment: Looks like the question is about the pieces shown for a file with different colors and not about the status of individual torrents.

Comment: @MK , thank you for making the question clearer, I've updated my answer.